# Set mouse click action in the center of the mouse pointer, not the top left corner

Tags: 11.04, compiz, mouse, cursor

Is there any way to alter the mouse pointer's action region?

I have a circle pointer with a dot in the center, and I want the mouse to start the action click from there, not from the top left corner, is there anyway to setup this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the "hotspot" of a cursor is defined inside the cursor file itself, so there must be a problem with the custom cursor you're using.

See [this](http://www.xfree86.org/current/xcursorgen.1.html) for instructions on how to create your own cursor - as you can see, the x and y coordinates of the hotspot are specified in the config file which is used to create a cursor.

Here is a thread about creating your own cursor theme - http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1440110